# change column with awk scripting

Tags: awk

I am trying to make a script B that uses another script A to change a specific column in a specific line. However, when I run the script A alone it runs perfectly. But when I try to use the script B (allowing me to run script A in other directories) it changes the entire line and not the specific column.

What is the problem?

script A (`0.MOF.run`):

```
#!bin/sh
echo $pot
mkdir u$pot  
cp u6000/towhee_input u$pot 
cd u$pot
mv towhee_input 1
awk < 1 -v k="-$pot.0" 'NR==12 {$2=k}{print}' > towhee_input   
cd ..
```

script B:

```
#!bin/sh
echo -n "Please Incert the Number of Potencials: "
read c
declare -i b
b=$c+1
rm pot_pid
a=1

while [ $a -lt $b ]
do
   pot=$(awk < data -v k="$a" 'NR==k ')

   . 0.MOF.mkdir
   . 1.MOF.run

   a=`expr $a + 1`   
done
```

Comment: i my sorry but i cant't edit properly the question.. i dont know how to do it

Comment: Can you be more precise? e.g In the 2nd script you call `1.MOF.run` but you said that your script is named `0.MOF.run`. Moreover to call a script _that is executable_ (`chmod +x myscript`) you should write `./myscript` or `/bin/bash myscript` ...

Comment: the 1.MOF.run, it's other script used to run simulations. The 0.MOF.mkdir, is a script to crated directories and change some parameters. The parameter that i wont to exchange is in the 2 column, and when i run the 0.MOF.mkdir alone it works perfectly.. but when i run it in the script B it change the entire line, not the specific column

Comment: I can't reproduce this, only the 12th line is changed in my tests. Please provide us with a minimal sample of input data that reproduces the problem for you. This is either somehow specific to your data or depends on the contents of `. 0.MOF.mkdir`. My guess is that whatever you are using to create `towhee_input` is not using the right field separators.

Comment: I see a problem of scope: check if it is true. In the scriptB it is given a values to the variable `pot`. Then there is the try to use it in the scriptA. If you do not pass this value somehow (`./scriptA  $pot` in _scriptB_, then  `pot=$1` in _scriptA_), the scriptA will not know the value of `pot` and it cannot act correctly in the `awk` call. As a side effect you should create a directory _u_ when you execute your script.

Comment: @Hastur He's using the `.` command to run the script, so it runs in the same shell. I don't know why he's doing it this way instead of passing command line arguments, but it should work.

Comment: Where is the `1.MOF.run` script? You've only posted `0.MOF.run`. If that was a typo, please correct it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Bamar: I agree if he runs it with `bash scriptB`. In my system `/bin/sh` is linked elsewhere (e.g. `/bin/dash`). I tested that if I run a similar script with `./scriptB` or `/bin/sh scriptB` it doesn't function even if I start from a `bash` shell. For him it's easy to check: it should create the directory `u$pot`. if `$pot` is empty it should create a directory _u_ and work there... if he finds a new directory named _u_ ... For the typo I said too:`0.MOF.run` is posted `0.MOF.mkdir` or `1.MOF.run` are called from the scriptB.Let we see what he will answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, I can't reproduce your issue. If you give us the data necessary to test, I will update this but in the meantime, here's a simpler way of writing what you have so far:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Write a function instead of calling
## an external script. You could also make
## 0.MOF.mkdir a function.
MOF_run() {
    echo "a.sh pot is $pot"
    ## The -p will cause mkdir to fail
    ## silently if the directory exists.
    mkdir -p u$pot  

    ## Run the awk on the target file, no need to cd or copy
    awk < u6000/towhee_input -v k="-$pot.0" 'NR==12 {$2=k}{print}' > u$pot/towhee_input   
}


echo -n "Please Insert the Number of Potentials: "
read c
## Make sure the user entered a number
## and not anything else or an empty string.
while [[ -z $c || ! $c =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a number."
    echo -n "Please Insert the Number of Potentials: "
    read c
done;
## increase c by one
let c++

rm pot_pid
a=1

while [ $a -lt $c ]
do
   pot=$(awk < data -v k="$a" 'NR==k ')
   echo "b.sh pot is $pot";
   . 0.MOF.mkdir
   ## Call the MOF_run function
   MOF_run

   ## increment $a
   let a++;
done
```